# Angular4 webpack2 @angular/material build error

Tags: angular, webpack-2, angular-material2

i can success on my development, but build it get errors, how should i do

Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'mdmenutriggerfor' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("Home Blog About ][mdmenutriggerfor]=theme>Theme    Blue Ocean   ][mdmenutriggerfor]=account>TaylorPzreal    ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'mdmenutriggerfor' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("Home Blog About ][mdmenutriggerfor]=theme>Theme    Blue Ocean   ][mdmenutriggerfor]=account>TaylorPzreal   http://localhost:3000/dist/vendor.b3014186753d08da08d0.js:2:451794) []
    at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:3000/dist/vendor.b3014186753d08da08d0.js:2:632968) []
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:3000/dist/vendor.b3014186753d08da08d0.js:2:819358) []
    at  [] Error: Template parse errors:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use selectors in list below instead of `mdmenutriggerfor`:

```
selector: `[md-menu-trigger-for], [mat-menu-trigger-for],
         [mdMenuTriggerFor], [matMenuTriggerFor]`,

<button md-icon-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu"> <md-icon>more_vert</md-icon> </button>
```

note: `[md-menu-trigger-for], [mat-menu-trigger-for]` is deprecated.

source: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/94320c4e68a8e6a2093b704157900cd6cd8388e2/src/lib/menu/menu-trigger.ts#L37-L38

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by two way:

1. replace 'html-loader' with 'raw-loader';
2. Comment out minimize line.

   ```
   new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
    htmlLoader: {
     minimize: DEVELOPMENT // workaround for ng2
    },
    // minimize: PRODUCTION, // Comment out this line
    debug: DEVELOPMENT,
    options: {
     context: __dirname
    }
   }),
   ```

Comment: what do you mean by this? I have the same problem so i need to fix this. where do I located "new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin ....

Comment: add it to plugins